# Have trouble with sed command on Linux

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed

I am facing some weird issue with `sed` command while replacing contents within a file. I created a dummy file with few lines and tried to execute my script. It worked.

The same script fails to replace the string when I use the `lvm.conf` file.

Task is to append disk path to the `global_filter` in `lvm.conf` file.

Input will be `/dev/sdb1` and I have to add the same to the `global_filter`
`global_filter = ["a|^/dev/sda2$|", "r/.*/"]`

My script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

function addToFilter(){
    app_lvm_conf="/etc/lvm/lvm.conf"
    line=$(sed -n '/global_filter =/p' $app_lvm_conf)
    echo $line
    exstngfltr=$(echo $line | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)
    echo $exstngfltr
    IFS=', ' read -r -a array <<< "$exstngfltr"
    echo ${array[@]}
    numOfEntries=${#array[@]}
    echo $numOfEntries
    value=$(IFS=,; echo "${array[*]}")
    echo $value
    temp="${array[numOfEntries-1]}"
    echo $temp

    ar=$1
    echo $ar
    a='"a|^'
    b='$|"'
    z=$a$1$b
    echo $z
    array[numOfEntries-1]=$z
    array[numOfEntries]=$temp
    newValue=$(IFS=,; echo "${array[*]}")
    sed -i "s@$value@$newValue@g" $app_lvm_conf
}
addToFilter $1
```

I have used multiple echo statements to see the output, I will remove them once the script is working fine.

---

Input is `"/dev/sda2"`

The expected output in `lvm.conf` file is:

```
global_filter = ["a|^/dev/sda1$|","a|^/dev/sda2$|","r/.*/"]
```

---

There will be one `global_filter` entry in `lvm.conf` file. On execution of this script, that filter should get updated.

Since that file is huge, I have copy pasted the section where `global_filter` is present into separate file and working on the same.

#### lvm.conf file

```
# Since "filter" is often overridden from command line, it is not suitable
# for system-wide device filtering (udev rules, lvmetad). To hide devices
# from LVM-specific udev processing and/or from lvmetad, you need to set
# global_filter. The syntax is the same as for normal "filter"
# above. Devices that fail the global_filter are not even opened by LVM.

global_filter = ["a|^/dev/dasda2$|", "r/.*/"]

# The results of the filtering are cached on disk to avoid
# rescanning dud devices (which can take a very long time).
# By default this cache is stored in the /etc/lvm/cache directory
# in a file called '.cache'.
```

On execution of the script, the file should change as below

```
# Since "filter" is often overridden from command line, it is not suitable
# for system-wide device filtering (udev rules, lvmetad). To hide devices
# from LVM-specific udev processing and/or from lvmetad, you need to set
# global_filter. The syntax is the same as for normal "filter"
# above. Devices that fail the global_filter are not even opened by LVM.

global_filter = ["a|^/dev/sda1$|", "a|^/dev/sda2$|", "r/.*/"]

# The results of the filtering are cached on disk to avoid
# rescanning dud devices (which can take a very long time).
# By default this cache is stored in the /etc/lvm/cache directory
# in a file called '.cache'.
```

The input to the script should be strictly of type `/dev/sda2`.

Comment: Yes, please show us your input and your desired output. Your script is far too complex for such a simple task.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to do but in `value=$(IFS=,; echo "${array[*]}")` the assignment to `IFS` is most definitely erroneous -- the `;` is a command separator and the assignment won't affect the environment of `echo`.

Comment: @AlexP - he's trying to [add a filter](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration/lvm_filters.html) to `lvm.conf`. The approach is far from ideal though... This can be done entirely in `sed` but requires some escaping... and -to make life easier- passing the exact filter to the script instead of just the device name.

Comment: @don_crissti: The point is that the assignment to `IFS` is a no-operation.

Comment: @AlexP it's a way to get `${array[*]}` to expand with comma separators in place of the default spaces - at least in bash. The IFS assignment is in the same subshell as the array expansion, so it *does* affect it. Try it ;)

Comment: Thanks for the edit but we need to see the *input file* and the desired *output file*. What does the `lvm.conf` file look like before your script and what is it supposed to look like after the script?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does what you need:

```
addition=', "a|^/dev/sda2$|"'
expression='/global_filter/ s@(, "r)@'"$addition"\\1'@'
sed -r -i.orig "${expression}" /etc/lvm.conf
```

The trick here is using the pattern matching of sed to match the line with /global_filter/,   and then using the search/replace, to just replace the bit around the comma:
   , "r

with your new addition.

The '-r' flag is required here for sed in order to capture the ' , "r   ' part with the parentheses '(pattern)' so that you can then re-insert it after your addition, using the backreference "\1"

Or, simpler to understand, without the -r and '()' matching:

```
addToFilter()
{
  device="${1}"
  addition='"a|^'"${device}"'$|"'

  insert_before=', "r'

  replacement=", ${addition}${insert_before}"

  line_match="global_filter"

  expression="/${line_match}/ s@${insert_before}@${replacement}@"

  sed -i.orig -e "${expression}" /etc/lvm.conf
} 

addToFilter "/dev/sda2"
```

I have assumed that 'dev/dasda2' in your example input file is not the true input, but was left there from a failed edit.